# Bug_Detected_In_Client_Of_UITableView_Invalid_Number_Of_Rows_In_Section Crash in SwiftUI

Tags: list, foreach, swiftui, ios14

I am running iOS 14.0.1, Xcode 12.0.1 targeting iOS14.

I have data in CoreData that I pull out and display in a SwiftUI List/ForEach. It was working fine on iOS13, but when I went to iOS14 is started getting intermittent crashes. After I add a new object to core data and then go back to the List/ForEach view it repaints the list but sometimes it over counts the number of elements and crashes with a Bug_Detected_In_Client_Of_UITableView_Invalid_Number_Of_Rows_In_Section. Since the array of entities from Core Data is observable and mapped directly to the List/ForEach I have no control over the count at all. It never crashes on the iOS 14 simulator, only on a real iPhone. It does not crash ever time I add a new entry, only sometimes seemly at random. It never crashed on iOS13 either on the simulator or a real iPhone.

This is the code to display the list;

```
    List {
      ForEach(self.locations, id: \.self) { location in
        LocationView(currentLocation: location)
      }
      .onDelete(perform: self.deleteSelectedRow)
    }
```

Is anyone else having this issue? It appears to be some internal bug to iOS14 ForEach processing with a CoreData created observable object, but if that were true I would think many people would be having the same issue, but I do not see any comments about this some sort of problem. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance for any an all ideas and help anyone can give!

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: That is a good idea. I will have to work on that. I thought about doing that first, but thought it better to first see if anyone had encountered this already.

Comment: I just wanted to add a comment that I had not forgotten about this. I found a work around and have a deadline to meet, but I will make a dummy program to show this error. Note that I fixed it by putting a write to core data in a timer. I suspect there is some kind of race condition going on. Here is the code I used to work around it.        _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false) { timer in
        do {
          try moc.save()
        }
        catch {  print("error")  }
    }

Answer (score 0):

the crash is due to the underlying TableView code inside SwiftUI framework.
Refer to this link for more info: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/129956?page=1#650267022

Comment: I tend to agree, but since this is within SwiftUI there is no way that I can see to fix that. I was able to obviate the bug by wrapping the write in a timer so that SwiftUI had a chance to get things in sync before displaying the list. This seems to be a bug in SwiftUI to me. I found it in iOS 13, and it is still there in iOS 14 as well.  Do you know any way to fix it?

Comment: Sure, delaying the write will help although it'll still intermittently caused crashed too because we can't really know when exactly the sync process is done. Unfortunately I can't find a way to fix that too, but I'm not facing the issue in iOS 14 anymore.. or is it just me? - sorry for the pun :)

Comment: Anthonius - How do you know you do not have the problem in iOS14? I think I still have the same problem in iOS14 as I did in iOS13. I have introduced a small wait time as I said above, and have not seen the issue since. But if I remove the wait the problem comes back. I tested that with iOS14.0, but have not tested in any of the subsequent smaller releases. If you tested it, which version of iOS14 did you test? I might have to go back and do some more testing now! Seems to me this is an Apple bug in SwiftUI, does that seem right to you?

Comment: Hi @JustMe, I'm testing in iOS 14.1 and without wait time, I'm not facing any crash. Yes, I agree it's bug in SwiftUI itself. I guess the issue is not solved in 14.0 but was patched in 14.1 :)

Comment: I just tested in 14.3 and the issue is gone as you noted with 14.1. I suspect you are right, that it was a bug introduced with 14.0 and fixed in 14.1. I am not going to go back to 14.1 or 14.2 to test it again, not worth the time. But it is fixed in 14.3 according to my own testing. I personally am leaving the timer in place even though it is fixed at it hurts nothing and I worry the issue is not fixed, just less prevalent (maybe only happens very 200 tries). I will probably remove the timer from my code with iOS 15.0. I am considering this issue closed for my own work.

Comment: Glad to hear that @JustMe personally I'm removing the timer to prevent that being a bad example for other devs.